# ASP.NET Core Model Bind Collection of Unknown Length

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to work out how to model bind a collection to a model property within asp.net core. I understand that the way this can be done is to include fields as so:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[0].Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[0].Name" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[1].Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[1].Name" />
```

However what do you do if you want to allow the user to add additional items and/or remove others. In this case I am adding these items client side using javascript and they might add a new item to the end and delete one from the middle, which could result in something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[1].Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[1].Name" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[3].Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="items[3].Name" />
```

ASP.NET Cores model binding doesn't then bind the collection to the model property (I presume because the indexes aren't aligned).

Is there any way to make this work? I'm trying to avoid having to write something to "relabel" the indexes of these fields.

**UPDATE**

For anyone else stumbling across this I add all of the elements to the page inside a container with the name of 0 like this:

```
<div class="some-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="id" asp-for="items[0].Id" />
    <input type="hidden" class="name" asp-for="items[0].Name" />
    <input type="hidden" class="id" asp-for="items[0].Id" />
    <input type="hidden" class="name" asp-for="items[0].Name" />
</div>
```

I then added the following to loop and rename them when the form was submitted.

```
$('#frmSomething').submit(function (e) {
    var selectors = $('.some-group');
    var id = 0;

    selectors.each(function (i, el) {
        var idItem = $(el).find('input.id');
        idItem.prop('name', idItem.prop('name').replace('0', id));

        var nameItem = $(el).find('input.name');
        nameItem.prop('name', nameItem.prop('name').replace('0', id));

        id++;
    });
});
```

This sequentially numbers the items only once a form is submitted meaning users can add and remove any combination of items they like without effecting the submission of values to the controller.

I'm sure someone could come up with a better way of solving this (I'm no javascript expert) but this works for me and might help someone else.

**UPDATE 2**

Answer provided below from @LukasKubris is correct, it's easier than writing a mapping function.

Comment: That's the only way. You must to manipulate the indexes. Rather than doing this manually, I'd recommend using something like Knockout or Angular, which can auto-generate your inputs based on a list of models in memory. You then simply push/pop items, and the client-side framework handles all the HTML for you.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt. I am trying to avoid pulling one of those in for such a small portion of usage at this stage.

Comment: Add a hidden input for the collection indexer so that non-zero/non-consecutive indexers are bound. Refer option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for an example. Refer also [Model Binding To A List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also bind **Non-Sequential Indices**. It just requires extra field called **Index**. So there is no need to have some helper JS functions.

```
<form method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="items.Index" value="7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b7" />
    <input type="text" name="items[7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b7].Key" value="key1" />
    <input type="text" name="items[7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b7].Value" value="value1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="items.Index" value="7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b8" />
    <input type="text" name="items[7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b8].Key" value="key2" />
    <input type="text" name="items[7466c69d-4575-4636-9151-f92edd9c25b8].Value" value="value2" />

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

usage in **OnPost** handler

```
public void OnPost(List<Item> items)
{
}
```

Comment: That's great, many thanks. I couldn't think of the right word for "non-sequential" to search for this.