# Model binding collection of Objects as one property of Model in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a PostEditViewModel class

```
 public class PostCreateViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Body { get; set; } 

    public string Descrition { get; set; } 
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; } 
    public List<ImagePath> ExistingPhotoPaths { get; set; }
}
```

and ImagePath class

```
public class ImagePath
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

in my edit view i try to hide the ExistingPhotoPaths property as

```
<input hidden asp-for="PostId" />

    @foreach (var path in Model.ExistingPhotoPaths)
    {
        i = i++;
        string x = val + i.ToString();
        <input type="hidden" name="ExistingPhotoPaths.Index" value="@x" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ExistingPhotoPaths[@x].Key" value="@path.ID" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ExistingPhotoPaths[@x].Value" value="@path.Path" />
    }
```

where val is a string used for binding Non-Sequential Indices mentioned in [ASP.NET Core Model Bind Collection of Unknown Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051665/asp-net-core-model-bind-collection-of-unknown-length) this question.

But using this method also my ExistingPhotoPaths property returning collection of null. i.e for suppose while get request ExistingPhotoPaths contains 3 ImagePath objects on post request it returning array of 3 null objects see below image, on post request see what ExistingPhotoPaths contains.

[image]

Am i using it correct way or suggest me to better way to do it and where i went wrong in my way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ExistingPhotoPaths.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ExistingPhotoPaths[i].ID" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ExistingPhotoPahts[i].Path" />
}
```

The syntax you're using currently, is for binding to a dictionary, not a list of objects, and foreach isn't going to work here, as Razor needs the entire model expression path to build the right input names.